# messy heatmap when plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe,df, with 29 rows and 92 columns with the rows being datetime Index and float as the column names representing the frequency of each of the column names day by day. I intend to plot a heatmap but i am getting a scattered plot. An example of dataframe looks like:

```
       Index                        0.0     1.0     2.0..... 91
      2017-08-03 00:00:00           10        0      10       0
      2017-08-04 00:00:00           20       60    1470      20
      2017-08-05 00:00:00           0        58       0      24
      2017-08-06 00:00:00           0         0     480      24
      2017-09-07 00:00:00           0         0       0      25
            :                       :         :       :      :
            :                       :         :       :      :
      2017-09-30 00:00:00
```

This is heatmap function that was called:

```
def heatmap(data, row_labels, col_labels, ax=None,
        cbar_kw={}, cbarlabel="", **kwargs):
"""
Create a heatmap from a numpy array and two lists of labels.

Arguments:
    data       : A 2D numpy array of shape (N,M)
    row_labels : A list or array of length N with the labels
                 for the rows
    col_labels : A list or array of length M with the labels
                 for the columns
Optional arguments:
    ax         : A matplotlib.axes.Axes instance to which the heatmap
                 is plotted. If not provided, use current axes or
                 create a new one.
    cbar_kw    : A dictionary with arguments to
                 :meth:`matplotlib.Figure.colorbar`.
    cbarlabel  : The label for the colorbar
All other arguments are directly passed on to the imshow call.
"""

if not ax:
    ax = plt.gca()

# Plot the heatmap
im = ax.imshow(data, **kwargs)

# Create colorbar
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax, **cbar_kw)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel(cbarlabel, rotation=-90, va="bottom")

# We want to show all ticks...
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries.
ax.set_xticklabels(col_labels)
ax.set_yticklabels(row_labels)

# Let the horizontal axes labeling appear on top.
ax.tick_params(top=True, bottom=False,
               labeltop=True, labelbottom=False)

# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=-30, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

# Turn spines off and create white grid.
for edge, spine in ax.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(False)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]+1)-.5, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]+1)-.5, minor=True)
ax.grid(which="minor", color="w", linestyle='-', linewidth=3)
ax.tick_params(which="minor", bottom=False, left=False)

return im, cbar


def annotate_heatmap(im, data=None, valfmt="{x:.2f}",
                 textcolors=["black", "white"],
                 threshold=None, **textkw):
"""
A function to annotate a heatmap.

Arguments:
    im         : The AxesImage to be labeled.
Optional arguments:
    data       : Data used to annotate. If None, the image's data is used.
    valfmt     : The format of the annotations inside the heatmap.
                 This should either use the string format method, e.g.
                 "$ {x:.2f}", or be a :class:`matplotlib.ticker.Formatter`.
    textcolors : A list or array of two color specifications. The first is
                 used for values below a threshold, the second for those
                 above.
    threshold  : Value in data units according to which the colors from
                 textcolors are applied. If None (the default) uses the
                 middle of the colormap as separation.

Further arguments are passed on to the created text labels.
"""

if not isinstance(data, (list, np.ndarray)):
    data = im.get_array()

# Normalize the threshold to the images color range.
if threshold is not None:
    threshold = im.norm(threshold)
else:
    threshold = im.norm(data.max())/2.

# Set default alignment to center, but allow it to be
# overwritten by textkw.
kw = dict(horizontalalignment="center",
          verticalalignment="center")
kw.update(textkw)

# Get the formatter in case a string is supplied
if isinstance(valfmt, str):
    valfmt = matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter(valfmt)

# Loop over the data and create a `Text` for each "pixel".
# Change the text's color depending on the data.
texts = []
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data.shape[1]):
        kw.update(color=textcolors[im.norm(data[i, j]) > threshold])
        text = im.axes.text(j, i, valfmt(data[i, j], None), **kw)
        texts.append(text)

return texts
```

So running the function with its argument, I used:

```
Rownames=list(df.index.values)
ColumnNames=list(df.columns.values)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im, cbar = heatmap(df, Rownames, ColumnNames, ax=ax,
               cmap="YlGn", cbarlabel="frequency [freq/day]")
texts = annotate_heatmap(im, valfmt="{x:.1f} ")

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

However i get this :
[image: the heatmap generated]

Comment: The code give for me a error `TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float`, which originates from the line `ax.imshow(data, **kwargs)`. Are you sure that there was no mistake during pasting it here?

Comment: Yes,there was no mistake. Thanks

Comment: You obviously have too much text in your figure, such that the heatmap is not seen any more. So the question is, do you really want to show each cell's value and all row-/column labels? If so, you will need to make the figure about a meter wide. If not, you might want to show only some of the values at the axes. If you then want to stick to the example you could set the rest to empty strings.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I intend to show each cell's value and all row-/column labels,so increasing the size worked using ''fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(40,40))''

Comment: It feels too large at one sight.Is there a way i can show the heatmap in a gliding manner